# Canvas draw new image from daturl

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm using the function below to resize and image using canvas

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = reader.result;
img.onload = function() {

    var max_width = 800;
    var max_height = 800;
    var tempW = img.width;
    var tempH = img.height;
     var aspect_ratio = 1;
    if (tempW > tempH) {
        if (tempH > max_height){
          var aspect_ratio = tempH / max_height
                       }
    } else {

            if (tempW > max_width){
          var aspect_ratio = tempW / max_width
                       }


    }
    tempH = tempH / aspect_ratio;
    tempW = tempW / aspect_ratio;

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
     canvas.id = "uploadedcanvas";
    canvas.width = tempW;
    canvas.height = tempH;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,tempW,tempH); 
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

   createsecondimage(dataURL,tempW,tempH,max_width,max_height,canvas)


   }
```

This is able to resize an image from taken from file reader. I would like to create a second image in the same canvas using the dataURL as the image source but this it does not seem to work this is what I'm doing

```
    function createsecondimage(dataURL,tempW,tempH,max_width,max_height,canvas){
var copy = document.createElement('canvas');
    copy.width = max_width;
    copy.height = max_height;
    var copyctx = copy.getContext("2d");
var sx = (tempW - max_width) / 2
    var sy = (tempH - max_height) /2
   copyctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    copyctx.fillRect(0,0,max_width,max_height); 
   var imgcopy = new Image();
        imgcopy.src = dataURL;
        imgcopy.onload = function() {
      copyctx.drawImage(imgcopy, sx, sy, 800, 800,0, 0, 800, 800);
var dataURL_ = copy.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        }
```

However datURL_ appears to be empty. I'm not sure why this is the case. Ideally I would want to create a new image using the image that was just resized.

Comment: Try setting imgcpy.src *after* onload. Also, use `copyctx.drawImage(this, ...)` instead of imgcopy.

Comment: i think you should wait with this line  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); until the canvas is drawn

Comment: @user3593876 excellent. I'll make it into an answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following two changes and it should work:

- set `imgcpy.src` *after* onload.
- Use `copyctx.drawImage(this, ...)` instead of `imgcopy`.

This way you are making sure decoding and setting of image is not completed before onload is called, and `this` will have a valid reference to the image being decoded.

Comment: This works, howevever dataURL_ is null. Do you know why this is the case.

Comment: @rolinstoner most likely a scope issue (based on the example code). You can pass it to a function which you call after setting it as image loading is async. Also check console for security errors (due to CORS). This can happen if the image was loaded from external site.